# Won't convert temperature

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple conversion form from celsius to fahrenheit and from fahrenheit to celsius. I can't figure out why it is not converting.

HTML

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="tempForm">
        <label for="temp">Temperature:</label>
        <input type="text" id="temp"><br>

        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="fahrenheit" checked />Convert to Fahrenheit <br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="celsius">Convert to Celsius  <br>

        <label for="resultField">Result: </label>
        <input type="text" id="resultField"><br>

        <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="processForm()">
    </form>

</body>
```

Javascript
    function processForm() {

```
var temperature = Number(document.tempForm.temp.value);
var tempType;
var result;

for (var i=0; i < document.tempForm.choice.length; i++) {

    if (document.tempForm.choice[i].checked) {
        tempType = document.tempForm.choice[i].value;
    }
}

if (tempType == 'fahrenheit') {
    result = temperature * 9/5 + 32;
}

else {
    result = (temperature -  32)  *  5/9;
}

// Assign the result field value here
result = document.tempForm.resultField.value;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the result the wrong away around at the end. You have to put the target of the assignment on the lefthandside of the assingment, hence you resultfield and on the righthandside the value you want to assign it to, like so:

```
document.tempForm.resultField.value = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion is working but you are assigning the result for `resultField` in a wrong way.

Convert the assignment (the last one) like this

```
document.tempForm.resultField.value  = result;
```